# Jquery animation queue problems

Tags: jquery, queue, jquery-animate

Having an issue with one my scripts. The animation keeps queueing up. I have searched your forums for solutions. I tried stop(true,true) and some variations of that as well as queue:false.

Maybe I just put it in the wrong spot, I'm not a 100% comfortable with jQuery just yet.

The function looks like this at the moment;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('div.wp-caption').each(function(i) {

        var img_ = $('img', this);          
        var img_height = img_.attr('height');
        var p_height = $('p', this).outerHeight();

        $(this).height(img_height);

        $(this).hover(function()  { 
            img_.animate({marginTop : -p_height}, 500);
        },  function()  {
            img_.animate({marginTop : '0'}, 500);
        });                 
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stop()` should work just fine if you put it before the `.animate()` method:

```
$(this).hover(function()  { 
    img_.stop().animate({marginTop : -p_height}, 500);
},  function()  {
    img_.stop().animate({marginTop : '0'}, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try clearing the animation queue:

```
            $(this).hover(function()  { 
                img_.stop(true, true).animate({marginTop : -p_height}, 500);
            },  function()  {
                img_.stop(true, true).animate({marginTop : '0'}, 500);
            });
```

The `true, true` arguments tell jQuery to clear the queue and jump to the end of the animation.

Comment: Nice one! That will surely come in handy. =)

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the `.stop()` before the `.animate`

```
$(this).hover(function()  { 
   img_.stop().animate({marginTop : -p_height}, 500);
},  function()  {
   img_.stop().animate({marginTop : '0'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Cheers! Thanks for contributing.